# How can I install and run mysqlworkbench on a remote Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, gui, mysql-workbench

I'm new to Ubuntu. I set up (currently only for testing and deploy) a remote Ubuntu Server 16.04.03.

Is it possible to install mysqlworkbench? As far as I know, there isn't any GUI on Ubuntu Server.

I downloaded and installed it, but if I try to launch it I get this error:

```
(mysql-workbench-bin:25719): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display
```

Comment: of course you can do `sudo apt install mysql-workbench`…

Comment: If you need a desktop environment on your ubuntu server, you can just install it with e. g. `sudo apt install lxde`.

Comment: I download and installed it, but if i try to launch it i receive the following error :                                                                                                                                                  (mysql-workbench-bin:25719): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Comment: You might find [Zentyal](http://www.zentyal.org/) interesting, it's basically a gui version of ubuntu server.

Comment: Please do not post error messages in comments. Comments can be deleted for a any number of reasons and the formatting is horrible. Please [edit] the question instead and use {} for code.

Comment: @Xauriello That's presumably due to the missing desktop environment. For a gui to work you'll need one, see my other comments.

Comment: OK, now is clear, so., in your opinion  the best gui can i install on ubuntu server 16.04.03 ? i need to use mysqlworkbench, kettle (pentaho) and if it's posbile have the way to connect by windows rdp. thanks in advance for all your support. basically i prefer i can lauch gui by command line (not automatically on boot)

Answer (score 2):

For a GUI to work on Ubuntu server you'll need a desktop environment of your choice. LXDE for example is a lightweight one that won't load your server too much, it can simply be installed with:

```
sudo apt install lxde
```

However, your server will still be fully configurable via terminal only. For a Ubuntu server with graphical interface like Microsoft Windows Server you might want to look into [Zentyal](http://www.zentyal.org/).

To remotely access a server I suggest to use `remmina`, see [its homepage](http://www.remmina.org/wp/), [Wiki](https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/wiki) and [FAQ](https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/wiki/Remmina-Usage-FAQ). If you connect to your server via `ssh`, there's the *X-Forwarding* function to display the gui of a program running on the remote server on your own screen. Use it like:

```
ssh -X user@server mysql-workbench &
```

Comment: Hi @dessert. now i installed lxde on my ubuntu server and reboot it. Now  i can i casse by terminal as before and it's ok. but if i wanto to connect to gui ? i need to run it from command line ? or i have to install some client on my ubuntu desktop pc ? server is not locate near me. thanks for all your support

Comment: @Xauriello I suggest you take a look at [remmina](http://www.remmina.org/wp/), it can be installed from the package sources on your desktop pc. Honestly I don't know very much about remote utilities, I'm afraid I can't help any more with that.